# JavaScript. Замыкание. Свободные переменные

Tags: javascript, замыкания

Привет всем. Изучаю JavaScript. Остановился на теме "Замыкание". Есть код

```
window.onload = function()
{
    var button = document.getElementById("clickme");
    var div = document.getElementById("message");
    var message = "You clicked me ";
    var count = 0;

    button.onclick = function()
    {
        count ++;
        div.innerHTML = message + count + " times!";
    }
};
```

В книге написано что в этот код содержит три свободные переменные `div, message, count`.

**Вопрос** А почему button не является свободным?

Простите за такой элементарный вопрос.

Comment: Если бы вы к `button` обращались внутри замыкания, то она бы тоже была свободной переменной.

Comment: Эм.. А какое определение у свободных переменных? Не встречал такого понятия, но предположил бы, что наоборот.

Comment: `Свободными переменными называются переменные в теле функции,
не связанные с данной функцией` определение из книги.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел определение, что "свободные переменные — это переменные, которые не объявлены локально и не передаются в качестве параметра". Если посмотреть в замыкание, то мы ссылаемся на `message`, `div` и `count`, которые как раз не передаются как параметры в замыкание и не объявлены в нем локально.

Позже заглянул в инструменты разработчика и обнаружил, что `this` хранит ссылку на `button` и считается локальной переменной. Получается, что `button` скорее контекст исполнения функции нежели переменная переданная в замыкание, что логично ведь мы пишем `button.onclick`, где `onclick` функция-замыкание, а `button` - объект в контексте которого она вызывается.

[image: Скриншот из инструментов разработчика]

Поправьте, если я ошибаюсь.